# How to get all rows from array using last column as criterion?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Anybody knows how to get all rows from this 2d array where last element=0 and save it in new array?

```
1 2 3 4 5 0
11 12 13 14 15 1
6 7 8 9 10 0
16 17 18 19 20 1
```

Up array (copied from `test.txt` file) contains two rows with last 0
and after split new tab must look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0
6 7 8 9 10 0
```

Will be great if solution can split for any last number or charin row.

I use this code to read from file and display on screen:

```
$tab = array();

$file = file('test.txt');
foreach ($file as $item) {
    array_push($tab, explode(' ', trim($item)));
};

foreach ($tab as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $value) {
        echo $value . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: the above doesn't look like *2d array*. Can you show the real structure?

Comment: do you want to obtain an additional array or to filter your  `$tab` array?

Comment: Additional arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a little modification from your code :)

```
<?php
$tab = array();

$file = file('test.txt');
foreach ($file as $item) {
    array_push($tab, explode(' ', trim($item)));
};

$array_new_number   = array();
foreach($tab as $row){
    $length = count($row);
    if($row[$length-1] == 0){
        //var_dump($row);
        array_push($array_new_number,$row);
    }
}

foreach($array_new_number as $item){
    foreach ($item as $value) {
        echo $value . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```